# which service converts element and attr names in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

AngularJS converts element and attr names between HTML markup and JS, replacing dashes with camelCasing, i.e. 'myComponent' -> 'my-component' (and back). which AngularJS service or function does this?

thanks
-nikita

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The actual function that does it is called `camelCase()` and it is found in [jqLite.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/jqLite.js) which in turn is taken from jQuery.

The use of that function is in the [compile stage](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js) in `directiveNormalize()`

**update**
The reverse is the function `snake_case()` in [angular.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js)

Comment: thanks; what about the reverse (ie snake case to camel case conversion). Or does Angular not have a need for that?

Comment: Updated the answer with the reverse as well

Comment: Is there any way to access `snake_case` function? I can see the function defined on Angular.js file, but I wasn't able to access it.

Answer (score 21):

In the directive definition object has a link function with 3rd parameter for attribute. This has a method $normalize which can do what you want

```
function link(scope, element, attrs) { 
 attrs.$normalize("my-test") //return myTest
}
```