# How to call source function from angular.js inside html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string

I want to the function "[angular.snake_case()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100031/which-service-converts-element-and-attr-names-in-angularjs)" in the html. This function is inside Angular.js file (the source itself).

Is it possible to call it as an angular expression = {{ }} ? 
Because an expression renders to scope.<*what I wrote in {{ }}*>, 
but this function is not on the scope.

Snippet:

```
... code

{{ angular.snake_case() }}

... code
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please include a snippet of code that you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

Grab the code you want and expose it through a directive.  Or you can implement this method in the `$rootScope`.

Comment: I don't want to rewrite a function which is already written in angular.js file, but I still want to access it like an expression.

Comment: that is not angular way !

Comment: If you could explain a bit more how to accomplish that, or give an example, it would improve your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assign it to scope model

```
$scope.snake_case = angular.snake_case;
```

In view:

```
{{snake_case(someVar)}}
```

That being said you probably would be better off just creating a filter.

I am also assuming that `angular.snake_case()` is part of the angular object ... I have never used it

Answer (score 1):

Use angularjs factory or service for making a function that's available in all controllers

Comment: Example: var module = angular.module('myapp', []); module.factory('MyService', function() {
     
    var factory = {}; 
 
    factory.method1 = function() {
            //..
        }
 
    factory.method2 = function() {
            //..
        }
 
    return factory;
});
    fac.users = ['John', 'James', 'Jake']; 
     
    return fac;
 
});